# `method_missing': undefined method `cache' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am having the mentioned error on a rails project, after I added the following line of code in the config/environments/development.rb

config.cache.store = :dalli_store

I am working on a personal project using Rails 4.2, installed on  OS X 10.7.5. Also memcached 1.4.5 is installed an running in my computer. I don't understand why this is happening. I want to use cache.store on my project but, I don't know how to solve this problem. Any help will be well received !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change:

```
config.cache.store = :dalli_store
```

to

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

Comment: Thank you Tai. That was the problem. Very appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

Guide says [Cache Stores](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores)

Rails provides different stores for the cached data created by **action** and **fragment** caches.

**Configuration**

You can set up your application's default cache store by calling `config.cache_store = :dalli_store`

> Alternatively, you can call ActionController::Base.cache_store outside
>   of a configuration block.

You can access the cache by calling `Rails.cache`

The cache store has a bounded size specified by the `:size` options to the initializer (default is 32Mb).

If you need to increase that then like below

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, { size: 64.megabytes }
```

And finally you written `config.cache.store = :dalli_store` that is wrong because Rails guide says `config.cache_store`

If you need to know more about Rails 4.2 Caching then please visit Rails official document about Cach [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/caching_with_rails.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Fool-dev for your valuable time and information.